# Handling right swipe in android wear activity

Tags: android, android-activity, wear-os

Is it possible to implement a wear activity which after launched can ***handle right swipe and launch other activity.***

More details. Lets say I have **ActivityA** which is the launcher of wear app. When  I do a right swipe can I make the **ActivityA** to launch **ActivityB**?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to handle right swipe:

You can try to write AndroidManifest.xml theme

android:theme="@style/Theme.Wearable.Modal inside activity tag

```
<activity
     android:name="com.smart.remote.wear.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Wearable.Modal">

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what is your issue, so I am guessing that you are referring to the fact that swipe to the right gesture is dismissing activities. You can disable this behavior and handle swipes right yourself. To disable this, you need to adjust the theme of your activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
</style>
```

More information about this can be found in the formal guide here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit.html